# Sort/Swap method in QtSpim returning unknown error

Tags: sorting, assembly, mips, swap, qtspim

This is my first time working with assembly, so I'm not sure where to start as far as troubleshooting goes. The program below is meant to sort an array. I believe my swap and sort methods are correct, however I am certain the main method is done incorrectly.

```
.data
array1: .word 2, 1, 3, 5, 4

.text
.globl main
main:
    # Initialize Registers
    lw  $a0, x      # Reg $a0 = x
    lw  $a1, y      # Reg $a1 = y

    # Call function
    move    $a0, $a0
    jal     sort
    move    $a1, $v0

    # print mag1
    li  $v0, 4
    la  $a0, mag1
    syscall

    # print result (y)
    li  $v0, 1
    move    $a0, $a1
    syscall

    # print newline
    li  $v0, 4
    la  $a0, lf
    syscall

    # Exit
    li  $v0, 10
    syscall

sort:   
    addi $sp, $sp, -20
    sw $ra, 16($sp)
    sw $s3, 12($sp)
    sw $s2, 8($sp)
    sw $s1, 4($sp)
    sw $s0, 0($sp)

    move $s2, $a0
    move $s3, $a1
    move $s0, $zero

loop1:  
    slt $t0, $s0, $s3
    beq $t0, $zero, exit1
    addi $s1, $s0, -1

loop2:  
    slti $t0, $s1, 0
    bne $t0, $zero, exit2
    sll $t1, $s1, 2
    add $t2, $s2, $t1
    lw $t3, 0($t2)
    lw $t4, 4($t2)
    slt $t0, $t4, $t3
    beq $t0, $zero, exit2
    move $a0, $s2
    move $a1, $s1
    jal swap
    addi $s1, $s1, -1
    j loop2

exit2:  
    addi $s0, $s0, 1
    j loop1

exit1:  
    lw $s0, 0($sp)
    lw $s1, 4($sp)
    lw $s2, 8($sp)
    lw $s3,12($sp)
    lw $ra,16($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 20
    jr $ra

swap:   
    sll     $t1, $a1, 2
    add     $t1, $a0, $t1   

    lw      $t0, 0($t1)         
    lw      $t2, 4($t1)         

    sw      $t2, 0($t1)         
    sw      $t0, 4($t1)         

    jr      $ra
```

The code then returns the following error:

```
Instructions reference undefined symbol at 0x00400024 [0x00400024] ;8: lw 

$a0, x # Reg $a0 = x
```

That seems to be a problem with defining variable `x`, which means the same thing will likely happen with variable `y`. What seems to be the issue and how can I resolve it?

edit:

```
Updated code
.data
x: .word 4
y: .word 5


.text
.globl main
main:
    # Initialize Registers
    lw  $a0, x      # Reg $a0 = x
    lw  $a1, y      # Reg $a1 = y

    # Call function
    move    $a0, $a0
    jal     sort
    move    $a1, $v0

    # print mag1
    li  $v0, 4
    la  $a0, mag1
    syscall

    # print result (y)
    li  $v0, 1
    move    $a0, $a1
    syscall

    # print newline
    li  $v0, 4
    la  $a0, lf
    syscall

    # Exit
    li  $v0, 10
    syscall

sort:   
    addi $sp, $sp, -20
    sw $ra, 16($sp)
    sw $s3, 12($sp)
    sw $s2, 8($sp)
    sw $s1, 4($sp)
    sw $s0, 0($sp)

    move $s2, $a0
    move $s3, $a1
    move $s0, $zero

loop1:  
    slt $t0, $s0, $s3
    beq $t0, $zero, exit1
    addi $s1, $s0, -1

loop2:  
    slti $t0, $s1, 0
    bne $t0, $zero, exit2
    sll $t1, $s1, 2
    add $t2, $s2, $t1
    lw $t3, 0($t2)
    lw $t4, 4($t2)
    slt $t0, $t4, $t3
    beq $t0, $zero, exit2
    move $a0, $s2
    move $a1, $s1
    jal swap
    addi $s1, $s1, -1
    j loop2

exit2:  
    addi $s0, $s0, 1
    j loop1

exit1:  
    lw $s0, 0($sp)
    lw $s1, 4($sp)
    lw $s2, 8($sp)
    lw $s3,12($sp)
    lw $ra,16($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 20
    jr $ra

swap:   
    sll     $t1, $a1, 2
    add     $t1, $a0, $t1   

    lw      $t0, 0($t1)         
    lw      $t2, 4($t1)         

    sw      $t2, 0($t1)         
    sw      $t0, 4($t1)         

    jr      $ra
```

Comment: your source does not define `x` and `y` anywhere, it's just trying to use it. And there's no such thing as "variables" in assembly, it's symbols pointing to certain place in memory, if you use particular symbol just for storing/loading value from there, it's sort of the mechanism which can be used by compiler to create a "variable", but in assembly you are free to do anything what is supported by the CPU with it, also things which are impossible with "variables" in high level languages.

Comment: To have some `x` symbol you can put into `.data` part something like `x: .word 7`, that will compile as four bytes of machine code (`7, 0, 0, 0` on little-endian systems, `0, 0, 0, 7` on big endian systems), defining word value `7`... then by `lw $a0,x` you will load that value 7 from memory into register `a0` (from memory address `x`). (but you can for example "break" into this "word variable" by doing for example `lb $a1,x`, loading just one byte of it, not whole word - that's something often not that easily achievable in high level languages (in C you can cast value to different type).

Comment: Okay, so I set x and y in .data, but now it's returning a bunch of Exception 7: Bad Data Address errors in the console.

Comment: update your question with new code.. for example your current code in question does not contain even `mag1`... read [MCVE] ... and learn to use debugger in QtSpim to identify the exact spot where the problem is happening and what it is. It takes lot of reading and experimenting to get the basics of asm programming, you may also want to follow some tutorial or get some lector or friend, it will be too tedious to keep asking about every basic detail on SO.

Comment: Okay, I did. I believe I am close, but I will mark this question as solved soon and try debugging more intensely. Apologies for not following the rules.

Comment: I tried to compile your updated code in MARS, and it fails on the `mag1` symbol being undefined. So I can't replicate your problem, works as expected for me, the undefined symbol gets reported during compilation as undefined, everything is ok here. (I'm not even sure what is your problem any more, as the problem with `x` was resolved successfully)

Comment: Okay, I think I solved it! Thank you again!